# Placing a charged sphere between two plates of a capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism

**What happens if I placed a small charged sphere between the two plates of a parallel-plate capacitor?**

Say the sphere has radius $R$, charge $Q$, and the plates are at a distance $l$ from eachother. For simplicity let's say the bottom plate is grounded and the top plate has potential $V_0$.

Depending on the distance $x$ from the sphere to the bottom plate, I expect that the sphere would feel a force from the two plates, and it's potential should change as well.

**How might I calculate this force/potential?**